# « Quasi » suivi d'une expression nominale

Tags: usage, adverbes, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Le pauvre garçon avait tant pleuré depuis trois jours et quasi trois nuits, qu'il était vanné par la fatigue, et même il se sentait d'un peu de fièvre, car il se tournait et retour
> nait sur son coussin, […]

[image]

[quasi trois](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quasi%20trois%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Apparemment, l'usage moderne serait « quasiment trois nuits ». Est-ce que « quasi » est utilisable généralement avant un groupe nominal ou bien est-ce qu'il existe une exception pour les groupes nominaux qui comportent un adjectif numéral ?

Par exemple la phrase suivante parait être non idiomatique.

- Il a travaillé quasi une journée pour faire ça.