# L'emploi de « quasi » devant un nom précédé d'un déterminant numéral cardinal est-il usuel etc. ?

Tags: usage, adverbes, déterminants, registre

> Le voici de retour sur le sol danois, après un voyage de quasi 10 ans.
> (AFP ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/2023-07-26/un-danois-a-fait-le-tour-du-monde-pendant-10-ans-sans-prendre-l-avion.php))

L'emploi adverbial de [*quasi*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quasi) pour *presque* devant un nom précédé d'un déterminant numéral cardinal est-il usuel (ou régional ou autrement), dans quel registre s'inscrit-il et doit-il prendre le trait d'union ?

Comment: Première fois que je vois ça.

Comment: Tiens, la question [a déjà été posée...](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52525/quasi-suivi-dune-expression-nominale) mais est restée sans réponse.

Comment: Le PO de l'autre question ne pourra accepter de réponse que dans un an. Il me semble qu'il vaut mieux dans ce cas laisser celle-ci active.

Comment: Il y a des POs qui ne reviendront jamais pour accepter une réponse.  Sans raison ou souvent ben disons normalement parce qu'ils ignorent ou s'en fichent du modèle SE ou ils trouvent une réponse très vite dans les commentaires.  Que faire avec ce doublon ? Est-ce un cas de *merge* ?

Comment: @livresque Parfois avoir une réponse acceptée peut décourager les contributions supplémentaires à mon avis. Je préfère sélectionner une réponse seulement quand elle a +3 ou plus et préférablement davantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le TLFi indique "*vieilli, familier, ou régional ou littéraire*" mais cette utilisation me parait assez courante. *Quasi* est utilisé comme abréviation de *quasiment*.

> *Au bout de quasi cinq ans, faut que je renouvelle mon stock de blagues. J'ouvre vers de nouveaux domaines...* [Twitter](https://twitter.com/bestlaf/status/259073304558714880)

> *Quasi douze mois après, alors que s'ouvre le procès en appel (toujours à Bordeaux, jusqu'au 27 mai), le personnage clé du dossier aborde ce 2 e round* [Le Parisien](https://www.leparisien.fr/archives/l-ami-de-liliane-de-retour-au-tribunal-10-05-2016-5781033.php)

> *A quasi quatre mois de la présidentielle d'avril 2022, la campagne électorale s'accélère et le casting se précise* [Les Echos](https://www.lesechos.fr/elections/presidentielle/presidentielle-2022-retour-sur-les-temps-forts-de-la-semaine-du-29-novembre-1369555)

> *Déjà huit familles ukrainiennes sont présentes sur la commune, ce qui représente quasi 20 personnes.* [Le Dauphiné libéré](https://www.ledauphine.com/societe/2022/04/03/montboucher-terre-d-accueil-pour-les-ukrainiens)

Remarque (Le bon usage, 14<sup>e</sup> ed., §990):

> Au sujet de *quasi* et de *quasiment*, les dict. et les
> grammaires émettent des jugements assez contradictoires, certains allant jusqu'à considérer que *quasi* est « en voie de disparition » et que *quasiment* « ne s'emploie plus guère que dans les parodies du
> langage paysan » (Wartburg-Zumthor, § 719).

Comment: Moi j'en suis resté à "presque" comme le suggère l'OP :-)

Comment: Merci, et ça reste dans un registre courant comme abréviation ? Est-ce que l'emploi comme abréviation de quasiment est le même emploi que quasi adverbe en soi ? Probablement que chez moi quasiment est tellement usuel et un peu vieillot que ça influence ma lecture, et on ne l'écourterait pas, un peu comme avec ma perception de promotion. Seuls les emplois avec des adjectifs me semble habituels.

Comment: Les avis divergent autour de moi. Certains trouvent que c'est familier, régional, d'autres pas. Je suis étonné de voir que le TLFi range *quasiment* presque dans le même sac (vieilli, fam., pop. ou rég.)

Comment: Je suis peut-être influencé par l'espagnol ou l'italien : *un viaje de casi diez años*, *un viaggio de quasi dieci anni*.

Comment: Pour ma part, dans mon entourage plutôt de l'est de la France, l'emploi de _quasi_ avec des années surprend. _Presque_ semble plus courant/naturel ici.

Comment: @Frank Mais est-ce que tu emploies *quasi* et/ou *quasiment* dans d'autres contextes ?

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, aucun problème dans _quasi parfait_, _quasi essentiel_, ... mais avec des nombres, surprenant. C'est juste le nombres qui font surprise apparemment.

Comment: @Frank Pas de problème à l'utiliser pour [George Sand](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52525/quasi-suivi-dune-expression-nominale): *Le pauvre garçon avait tant pleuré depuis trois jours et quasi trois nuits, qu'il était vanné par la fatigue, et même il se sentait d'un peu de fièvre, car il se tournait et retournait sur son coussin*